# GRE topology definition

Tags: general-topology

So on a certain GRE subject problem they define for a given a subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$

$$Y' = \{x \in X : x \in \text{cl}(Y \setminus \{x\})\}$$

Where $\text{cl}$ is closure. Is this just a fancy definition for the set of limit points of $Y$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes your are correct Y' is the set of limit points of Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is clear after you know that $\operatorname{cl}(Y)= \{x \in X: \forall O \text{ open }: (x \in O) \to (O \cap Y \neq \emptyset) \}$ for all $Y \subseteq X$ the closure of $Y$ is the set of points $x$ such that each (open) neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $Y$. A limit point of $Y$ is the same except that each neighbourhood of $x$ must contain a point of $Y$ *different from* $x$ itself, which in fact says that $x$ is in the closure of $Y\setminus \{x\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  This is known as the *derived set*, and is typically denoted with a 'prime'.

If the space is $T_1$, one can say that $Y'$ consists in those points $x $ for which there exists a non-trivial *net* in $Y $ converging to $x $.

A net is a generalization of a sequence.

Comment: so you can put a ball around $x$ intersecting $Y$ non-trivially? I can see that, thanks!

Comment: Surely, the existence of such a sequence surely requires a countable neighborhood basis at each point (first countability), or some other assumption. The need for nets to fully account for convergence in arbitrary topological spaces would suggest that this is not true in general.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887906/is-a-limit-point-in-a-sequential-space-the-limit-of-some-sequence). I think that gives an example of a limit point that is not a sequential limit point.

Comment: @Arturo I made too general a statement.   Perhaps I can correct it by replacing 'sequence' with 'net', as you seem to suggest.

Comment: I  suspect the space needs to be $T_1$, even for that.

Comment: Nets should be fine, since you can take the whole system of neighborhoods partially ordered by reverse inclusion as your index set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Chances are one could also use Henri Cartan's _filters_, though they do not directly generalize sequences,  and can thus be considered a bit more difficult to learn.